# List addons of Firefox in C# .Net 4.0

Tags: c#

I need to list the addons (plugins and extensions) of Firefox.
This list will be used later (in program) to verify and/or delete (in case of a bad plugin such as Conduit etc...).

Using a database isn't a option (allthou it would made it easier).
I try to use SQLite but is somehow clashes with my SQL CE local database.

So.. (I guess) I've got to use the users preferences (prefs.js) situated in

```
%APPDATA%\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\3cjueis1.default
```

(This path I can get from `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini`)

What is the best way to do this?

**UPDATE**

From Firefox 26.0 onward, addons.sqlite is replaced with addons.json. This is a JavaScript Object Notation a open standard format that uses human-readable text. Information: [Mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/982446?esab=a&s=&r=0&as=s)

Comment: What are you having trouble with exactly?

Comment: To list out the addons (plugins and extensions) such as Java/Flash/Adblock plus/etc...

Comment: That directory contains the databases of Firefox, one of them named *addons.sqlite* containing all information you need. It'll likely be easier than reading the contents of the *extensions* directory.

Comment: Yes, I know, but as I wrote in my first post: "using a database isn't a option". Because this requires to install the database engine (in VS 2010) and deploy it for the user as well.
And I don't wanna do that .

Comment: But that database ships with Firefox no matter what. You wouldn't have to deploy an engine and set up your own.. You just read that sqlite db..

Comment: Indeed, all you need is the library from http://system.data.sqlite.org

Comment: If I do that it clashes with my SQL CE local database.

Comment: So you're having trouble using the SQLite provider and SQL CE provider simultaneously? Then perhaps you should open a new question to solve that issue and remove this question.

Comment: No, I know for a fact that it is possible to list out Firefox addons not using the SQLite database. My question is how they do that. ( without the database)

Comment: If you really want to do this; as I mentioned there's also an *extensions* directory. The `.xpi` files are ZIP files, so you need to unzip them and read the `install.rdf` file to retrieve information about the extension.

Comment: Aaahhh...yes, that would be a possibility.
Thanks so much :)

Comment: From Firefox 26.0 onward, *addons.sqlite* is replaced with *addons.json*.

This is a *JavaScript Object Notation* a open standard format that uses human-readable text.

Information:

[Mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/982446?esab=a&s=&r=0&as=s)